# external file loads with main page CSS file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page am using onclick to load external html file

#### main page

- In main page I have 3 CSS file linked in `HEAD` tag, `bootstrap`, `main.css`, `icon.css`

#### external page

- In external page I have only one CSS file `style.css`

#### ERROR

- When external file loads it links with `bootstrap.css`. How do I stop the external page link with bootatrap.css`?
- How do I link only `style.css file`  to link with external file?

All CSS file are linked in head tag of specific file, and external file is loaded inside DIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every CSS you load on a page is available for all the elements on that page. There's no way to separate them by their origin. But you can specify an id for the element you load the external page into, and define/override styles just for it.

```
#containedIdHere {
    ...
    specific rules
    ...
}
```

Other selectors work fine as well:

```
#containedIdHere .someClass {
    ...
    specific rules
    ...
}
```

Comment: but i have more than 250 class and its hard to mention its id

Comment: am loading external page in DIV tag how do i stop other css file link for specific div

Comment: `"There's no way to separate them by their origin."` You might be able to hack it by using iframes.